# Programatically creating the custom UICollectionViewCell and setting the properties

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I've been trying to configure a custom UICollectionViewCell that is supposed to present a UIView consisting of a few subviews generated with a custom method.

The problem is that when I try to pass the needed data from -cellForItemAtIndexPath to the cell's properties (NSStrings) the app crashes and the data doesn't seem to be passed at all, because NSLog returns (null) for all of the properties.

I thought that the problem was with the properties not being initialized, but when I initialized them in -initWithFrame, they didn't return any values. I tried to use the -initWithCoder and -awakeFromNib and it didn't work.

I also tried to utilize a custom method that would set the properties for me. While it seems to be working, I can't seem to find a way to add the generated view to the cell's view, as using [self.contentView addSubview:...] seems to be adding every generated view to every cell in the Collection View.

If you guys could help me out, I would be much grateful - I've spent my entire day on this, and I just can't get it to work. Perhaps I should do it differently?

My custom collection view cell's .h file:

```
#import "SHDesignChicago.h"

@interface SHDesignChicagoCollectionViewCell : UICollectionViewCell

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *name;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *date;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *going;

@property (strong, nonatomic) PFFile *background;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIView *generatedDesign;

- (void)setCellWithEventName:(NSString *)name eventDate:(NSString *)date eventGoing:(NSString *)going eventBackground:(PFFile *)background;

@end
```

And my custom collection view cell's .m file:

```
#import "SHDesignChicagoCollectionViewCell.h"

@implementation SHDesignChicagoCollectionViewCell

- (void)setCellWithEventName:(NSString *)name eventDate:(NSString *)date eventGoing:(NSString *)going eventBackground:(PFFile *)background {

    UIImage *backgroundImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[background getData]];

    NSLog(@"Event details:\nName: %@\nDate: %@\nGoing: %@\nBackground: %@", name, date, going, background);

    self.generatedDesign = [SHDesignChicago designWithName:name date:date going:going background:backgroundImage frame:self.frame];
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];

    if (self) {
        //self.autoresizesSubviews = YES;

        __block UIImage *backgroundImage;
        [self.background getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
            if (!error) backgroundImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
        }];

        NSLog(@"Event details:\nName: %@\nDate: %@\nGoing: %@\nBackground: %@", self.name, self.date, self.going, self.background);
        if (self.name != nil) {
            UIView *generatedDesign = [SHDesignChicago designWithName:self.name date:self.date going:self.going background:backgroundImage frame:self.frame];
            [self addSubview:generatedDesign];
        }

    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

Also the cellForItemAtIndexPath:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    PFObject *event = [self.events objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSString *name = event[@"eventName"];
    NSDate *date = event[@"eventDate"];
    PFFile *background = event[@"coverPhoto"];

    if ([event[@"designId"] isEqual: @(1)]) {
        // SHDesignChicago
        SHDesignChicagoCollectionViewCell *chicagoCell = (SHDesignChicagoCollectionViewCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"chicago" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        /*
        chicagoCell.name = @"TEST";
        chicagoCell.date = @"TODAY, 5 PM";
        chicagoCell.going = @"NATALIA KAWECKA AND 35 OTHERS ARE GOING";
        chicagoCell.background = background;
        */

        [chicagoCell setCellWithEventName:name eventDate:@"TODAY, 5 PM" eventGoing:@"NATALIA M AND 35 OTHERS ARE GOING" eventBackground:background];

        return chicagoCell;
    }

    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Please let me know if I should explain something more clearly.

Comment: You're right that you can't initialize your view with data in `initWithFrame:` because the properties won't have been set yet.  The way you are doing it with the `setCellWithEventName` method is good, but you don't want to create the view in that method since it will be getting called multiple times and you don't want to add multiple copies of the view.  You should add your `SHDesignChicago` view in `initWithFrame:` and then only update the properties of that view in `setCellWithEventName` and not create a new view.

Comment: @dan so, if I understand correctly, in -setCellWithEventName I have for example `self.name = name` and then in -initWithFrame I'm supposed to use those global properties? I'm asking because it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: `initWithFrame` gets called first and won't be called again, you can't use any of your cell's properties there because they won't be set.  In `setCellWithEventName` you should be doing `self.generatedDesign.name = name` and your `SHDesignChicago` view should update it's interface in the setters of those properties.

Comment: Hey can one of y'all help me out as well? I think my question is similar but not 100% sure what I need to do to fix it. Here's my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34441133/custom-uicollectionviewcell-properties-are-null-after-dequeueing

Comment: Do you mind outlining or showing some examples of the changes you made to fix this?