# Custom UICollectionViewCell properties are null after dequeueing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

So I have a UICollectionView and a custom cell and it all shows up and works great. I register the class in viewDidLoad:

```
myCollectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:collectionViewFrame collectionViewLayout:layout];
[myCollectionView setDataSource:self];
[myCollectionView setDelegate:self];
[myCollectionView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor myColor]];
[myCollectionView registerClass:[SBCustomCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
```

In my cellForItemAtIndexPath method I dequeue the cell and set its properties and return it:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *identifier = @"Cell";

SBCustomCell *cell= [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

[cell setName: "My Name"];
cell.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"lol.png"];
cell.score = 100.0;
cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];

return cell;
}
```

This all works fine and it shows up in the UI. My issue is when I set a gesture recognizer on the collectionView, when I long press a certain cell, I want to be able to access its properties. I am trying to do so as such:

```
-(void)handleLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)longPressRecognizer {

CGPoint locationPoint = [longPressRecognizer locationInView:myCollectionView];

if (longPressRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {

    NSIndexPath *indexPathOfMovingCell = [myCollectionView indexPathForItemAtPoint:locationPoint];

    SBCustomCell *cell= [myCollectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPathOfMovingCell];

    NSLog(@"%@",cell.name);
```

When I try to access any of my custom cell's properties, it is (null) in console. Why is that? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use:

```
SBCustomCell* cell = (SBCustomCell*)[myCollectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPathOfMovingCell];
```

instead of:

```
SBCustomCell* cell = [myCollectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPathOfMovingCell];
```

Also, you are using `SBSingleCandidateUnitView` as the cell type instead of your `SBCustomCell`.

Comment: Hey Mike, thanks for the reply. Actually I do have it as SBCustomCell I was just editing the code for use on StackOverflow and forgot to change that one. My question is why would I not use the dequeue method? I want to get back a custom cell not a generic UICollectionView cell. The generic cell does not have the custom properties that I set.

Comment: @stellarowl12: You don't use dequeue because that gives you a "new" cell to add to the collection view. Even though the method returns a UICollectionViewCell, you can cast it to the type of cell it actually is. I've updated my answer to show this.

Comment: So I casted it and there are no errors or warnings, however when I try to use NSLog to print out any of the custom cell's properties that I set in cellForItemAtIndexPath, they all still print out as Null.... any idea why this is the case? Am I setting it at the wrong place?

Comment: @stellarowl12: Sorry, I don't think I could really give you any accurate idea why it's doing that. Debugging is your best bet here, I think.

Comment: So just to clarify. I can use the dequeue stuff in the cellforitematindexpath but not in the handleLongPress method, right?

Comment: @stellarowl12: Yes. Dequeueing is for getting a "new" cell to add to the table view. Accessing a particular cell already in the table view is done with the `cellForItemAtIndexPath` method.

Comment: I figured it out, it had to do with my properties in my custom cell file. Thanks for your help Mike

Comment: Awesome. Congratulations. And no problem, glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

It was because I wasn't setting my properties correctly. In my header file I need to be setting a property, aka @property ... UIImageView myImageView;

And in my CustomCell.m file I should be not overriding those setters and getters. Instead just alloc and initing them and adding them to the view.

And back in my ViewController.m I should have added the properties as such:

customcell.myImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cartman.png"];